# where clause and case statement giving empty records in select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Tb_patientBeds`.

Now I want to retrieve the records set as *occupied*, *unoccupied* or all based on the `status` column in this table.

Here are my other columns:

```
patientBedID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
patientBedType [varchar](20) NULL,
BedCharge [varchar](20) NULL,
status [varchar](20) NULL,
```

I wrote the query like

```
select * from Tb_patientBeds where [status]= case
when [status]= '0'
then 'occupied'
when [status]='1'
then 'unoccupied' else 'All'
end
```

The query is not returning records, it's showing empty records.

Could anybody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN [status] = 1 THEN
        'unoccupied'
    WHEN [status] = 0 THEN
        'occupied'
    ELSE
        'All'
    END,
    *
FROM Tb_patientBeds
```